# Angular material md-form-field doesn't work as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am using @angular/material 2.0.0 beta.10

In the appModule, I imported the MdFormFieldModule, MdInputModule.

My html looks like this:

```
<md-form-field>
  <input type="text" mdInput placeHolder="Hi">
</md-form-field>
```

I don't get any error, but the input looks like a regular html input.

There is no floating label, no color on the line on focus etc.

What am I missing? do I need to import some css?

Answer (score 0):

In the index.html page need to add a reference to the required theme

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The «md-» prefix has been replaced by «mat-» in the latest version. So according to [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) your code should be something like

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I am using material beta 10 for now. see the solution I found.